# How to get workflow Blocking Bookmarks(statemachine) without relying on workflow persistence service

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

I need to get the next activities(transitions) what my workflow is being blocked for as soon as workflow entered a new state without relying on workflow persistence service, I found out that workflow persistence start to hit database when workflow instance is idle, which has a time latence when there are more than one instance of workflow running, it pose a serious problem for me, I need the blooking bookmarks to be in Synch with my workflow status, which I will set in code activity when workflow enters its new state, from codeActivityContext and NativityContext, there is no way to get the api to get this information(the next transitions), both the statemachine class and state class are sealed, there is not way to tag into it.I am using the blocking bookmarks to indict how the workflow will flow to U.I, so that I can drive the workflow from U.I, I am hosting the statemachine using workflowserviceHost with IIS. I am wondering why I am the only one run into this issue, I have been struggle with this issue for some time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your best options is using a TrackingParticipant where you can see exactly what is going on in a workflow as it is executing. From the TrackingParticipant you can then save the bookmarks and have the UI reuse them.